# Select table without id and iterate all href

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this HTML with 2 Dropbox and one button.

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <select id="dep1" >
   <option>Info</option>
   <option>Mecanique</option>
  </select>
 </td>

 <td>
  <select id="dep2" >
   <option value="001">Glid</option>
   <option value="002">ASR</option>
   <option value="003">Electronique</option>
  </select>
 </td>
 <td>
  <input id="selection" type="submit" onclick="return check2()" value="Go"></input>
 </td>
</tr>
</table
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is when I select Info in 1st Dropbox, the 2nd will show Glid and ASR, then when I click on the button it will open another tab and go to another web site. 
For now I try to go the websiteand select 1st dropbox and save all result of 1st dropbow in txt file

```
IWebDriver driver;
        string url = "My site";
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("dep1"))).SelectByText("Info");
        var result = driver.FindElement(By.Id("dep2")).Text;
        File.WriteAllText("result.txt", result);
```

My problem here that how I can add the value exist in option to the text and show like this:

> 001 Glid 
>  002 ASR

and for 2nd problem, I have with some other HTML code like this :

```html
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="site1">Glid</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="site1">ASR</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="site1">Electronique</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

So it's the same problem, how can I get the href of the selected option without knowing the table id?

Comment: Why are you putting them in a table?

Comment: not me, that's what it looks in the web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the tables elements:

```
IList<IWebElement> options = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#dep2 > option")); //get all option tags from the table
IList<IWebElement> hrefs = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")); //get all hrefs

foreach (IWebElement option in options)
{
    string value = option.GetAttribute("value");
    string text = option.Text;

    foreach (IWebElement href in hrefs)
    {
        if (href.Text.equals(text))
        {
            // do what you need with the href
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there 2 errors: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' and  'IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'GetText' and no extension method 'GetText' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebElement'

Comment: For options get 0 count, and href 66 count

Comment: I add some code to save the result in txt file, but it shows only name, I want add the links too :String[] allText = new String[hrefs.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (IWebElement element in hrefs)
            {
                allText[i++] = element.Text;
            }

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("result.txt");
            foreach (String s in allText)
                tw.WriteLine(s);

            tw.Close();

Comment: Try to split options to two lines, `IWebElement dropdown = driver.FindElement(By.Id("dep2"));` `IList<IWebElement> options = dropdown.FindElements(By.TagName("option"));`. If it doesn't work at least you can tell what the driver can't find.

Comment: As for the href, there are many a tags in the html (well, 66...), but I can only build path based on the html you posted here. Try to find unique path that work.

Comment: By the way, if the href looks like `<a href="/mySite/gild/">Glid</a>` `<a href="/mySite/asr/">ASR</a>` you can find them using `driver.FindElements(By.CssSelecyor("[href*='/mySite']"));` That will give you all the hrefs that contains `'/mySite'`

Comment: thnx it was so helpful